# Form not submitted after a second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I try to submit a form if a condition is not validated.

```
$("#support_form").submit(function() {
  if($("#id_reward").attr('value')=="" && $('.reward_item.none.selected').length==0) {
    alert('problem');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('valid');
    return true;
  }
});
```

If my form is valid on the first call, my form is well submitted (redirection to another page)

If my form is not valid the first time, and I correct it then, I see the alert box "valid", but my form is not submitted.

Do you have an idea about this problem ?

Comment: Something else is going on.  Chop the page down to a small -- but complete -- webpage that demonstrates the problem.  Then edit your question to include that code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but doing something like $('.reward_item.none.selected') is really bad for performance.  Your entire DOM has to be scanned to search for the classes.  If you know for certain that it is a div element, use this instead: $('div.reward_item.none.selected').